# Comma in numbers causing problem reading csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Upon calling a csv file I am getting the following error

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 12, saw 2
```

I opened my csv file and then went to the line and saw that the error is coming because one of the numbers is with decimals but separated by a cooma.

That entire column of my csv file has whole numbers but also decimals numbers that look like the following .

```
385433,4
```

Not sure how I can resolve this error when reading the csv file using pandas

Comment: `pd.read_csv(filename, decimal = ',')`

Comment: @Sayandip Dutta, for some reason I am getting the same error

Comment: What does the rest of the data look like?

Comment: Show a few *actual* lines of the CSV file (change sensitive data if needed).

Comment: @Mark Tolonen, my lines are separated by ```;``` and the if I remove that line the next error comes exactly at the other lines that has a decimal number seperated by a comma example ```154,65 ```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have European-formatted CSV.  Since you haven't provided a real sample of your CSV as requested, I will guess.  If this doesn't solve your issue, *edit your question to provide an actual sample*:

Given `test.csv`:

```
c1;c2;c3
1,2;3,4;5,6
3,4;5,6;7,8
```

Then:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('test.csv',decimal=',',delimiter=';')
print(data)
```

Produces:

```
    c1   c2   c3
0  1.2  3.4  5.6
1  3.4  5.6  7.8
```